# fetch empty list to FlatList with react native

Tags: php, sql-server, react-native

I am developing a react native app where I should enter a specific year and month to fetch data from my SQL server DB.

My problem is sometimes my list can be empty like when I use 2020/20, In this case, I get an error msg (Tried to get a frame for out of range index NaN ) How can I manage this problem???

This is my code :

```
userRegister = () =>{
    const month = this.state.month;
    const year= this.state.year;
    return fetch('http://192.168.1.12:80/fetch.php',{
    method:'post',
    header:{
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-type' :'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({mois:month,annee:year})})
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        }
      );

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });

      this.setState({
      month:'',
      year:'',})
  }


  render(){
    if(this.state.isLoading){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>

    <View style={{backgroundColor:'#58ACFA',flex:2,justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:32,marginLeft:20}} onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer }>
          <FontAwesome5 name="bars" size={24} color="#161924" />
          </TouchableOpacity >
          </View>

          <View style={{flex:8 ,flexDirection:'row' }}>
          <View style={styles.pass}>
          <TextInput placeholder='year n' style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}} onChangeText= {year=>this.setState({year })}/></View>
          <View style={styles.pass}>
          <TextInput placeholder='Month n' style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}} onChangeText= {month=>this.setState({month })}/></View>
    <View style={styles.pass}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.butt} onPress={this.userRegister}>
              <Text style={{marginTop:8,color:'grey'}}>Afficher</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity></View>
          </View>
      </View>

    )
  }


      return(
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>

  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#58ACFA',flex:1,justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:32,marginLeft:20}} onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer }>
        <FontAwesome5 name="bars" size={24} color="#161924" />
        </TouchableOpacity >
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1 ,flexDirection:'row' }}>
        <View style={styles.pass}>
        <TextInput placeholder='year n' style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}} onChangeText= {year=>this.setState({year})}/></View>
        <View style={styles.pass}>
        <TextInput placeholder='Month n' style={{flex:1,paddingLeft:5}} onChangeText= {month=>this.setState({month})}/></View>
  <View style={styles.pass}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.butt} onPress={this.userRegister}>
            <Text style={{marginTop:8,color:'grey'}}>Afficher</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity></View>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:7 ,paddingLeft:10 ,paddingTop:10 ,paddingBottom:10}}>


        <View  style={{ flexDirection:'row' }}>
        <Text  style={styles.head}> Client </Text>
        <Text  style={styles.head1}>Mois</Text>
        <Text  style={styles.head2}>Annee</Text>
        <Text  style={styles.head3}>ChiffreAffaire</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        renderItem={({item}) =><Item title={item.M500_NOM} title1={item.Mois} title2={item.Annee} title3={item.ChiffreAffaire}/>}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

        />
</View>
    </View>

    );
```

And this is my PHP page :

```
<?php

$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"Netos_DB","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"123");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);


$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

     $obj = json_decode($json,true);


    $mois = $obj['mois'];

    $annee = $obj['annee'];

   if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else{
 $sql = "select TOP 80* from V502_client where Mois='$mois' and Annee='$annee'"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

  while( $row[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $Item = $row;
      $json = json_encode($Item);}

    echo $json;
}

?>
```

Comment: One note - do not concatenate user input to build the SQL statement. Always use prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. With PHP Driver for SQL Server, function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.

Comment: Do you mean to do this:
$sql = "select TOP 80* from V502_client where Mois=? and Annee=?";
    
$params=array($mois ,$annee);

   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql ,$params );

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to use parameters.

Comment: Ok ,but I still have the same problem as before

Comment: @As I said, it's just a note. I have no experience with `react-native`, but your PHP code (when you use parameters) seems correct.